# Why does it take so long to get an item?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

I have been playing Mario Kart Wii for quite a while, and when I started watching Mario Kart Wii videos on YouTube, I noticed that a lot of the players get their items from item boxes much faster (the CPUs in 1P mode also get items faster). What I mean by this is that it takes longer for the item to choose itself and to become usable from the point where I collect the item box. Why does it take longer for me than other players to get the item? Is this caused by a hidden feature, or possibly by a cheat code?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Pressing the "Use Item" button repeatedly while the picked up item is still "spinning" will get you the item much faster.

Comment: I was timing this so I could write an answer, but since you were faster, I'll just report my findings here: If you wait for the slot to stop spinning, it takes ~3.7 seconds to get the item. If you press the "Use Item" button, you can get it as early as ~2 seconds (possibly even earlier).

Comment: It's all part of an insidious plan to get us wearing out our controllers sooner and thus needing to buy new ones more often …

Comment: @can-ned_food: A lot of games' fanbases really like to struggle against the user interface. I bet that's a big part of the reason why this "feature" continues to exist.

Comment: Note that this feature was iirc already present on the game cube version of mario kart.

Comment: I believe this is even already present since the first *Mario Kart* series on SNES. Also,not sure about *Mario Kart Wii*, but on SNES version, I believe you only need to press the button once (not repeatedly) after it has passed a certain minimum time (as experimented by Nolonar).